# Consuming data from Azure event hub using structured streaming kafka

Tags: apache-kafka, spark-streaming

I am using structured streaming kafka integration to stream data from event hub and print in console as below example, but I get nothing on the console even if I am able to show the data in console using org.apache.spark.eventhubs structured streaming API.

```html
import org.apache.spark.sql.kafka010._

val spark = SparkSession.builder()
    .master("local[*]")
    .appName("kafkaeventhubconsumer")
    .getOrCreate()

val df = spark
  .readStream
  .format("kafka")
  .option("kafka.bootstrap.servers", "<EVENT_HUB_FQDN>:9093")
  .option("subscribe", "<EVENT_HUB_NAME>")
  .option("security.protocol", "SASL_SSL")
  .option("sasl.mechanism" , "PLAIN")
  .option("sasl.jaas.config", """org.apache.kafka.common.security.plain.PlainLoginModule required username="$ConnectionString" password="<CONNECTION_STRING>";""")
  .load()
  
df.writeStream.outputMode("append").format("console").option("truncate", false).start().awaitTermination()
```